# Siri provides incorrect business hours

Tags: siri, maps

When a customer asks Siri my business hours the reply they received is not correct.  I have looked everywhere to determine where Siri is pulling this information, but cannot find the hours listed this way anywhere.
I am tired of customers getting upset when they get to my store and find out we open at 10 and not 9.  BTW, we have never opened at 9.

Answer (score 1):

Apple crowd sources information. Once someone reports a location, it is reviewed and the added to the database. Apple also has in the past used third parties to source its geographical information - especially in non USA regions.

No matter how Apple started your listing, you can claim it and correct the presentation here:

- https://www.apple.com/business/connect/